# Javascript switch statement for menu drop list

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working on doing a switch statement for a menu drop list in javascript and have the following code so far (the script is in the head and the rest is in the body, and the map_img1, etc. is a url):

```
<script>
    function selectTrafficCamera(inobj) {
        switch(inobj) {
            case "0":
                document.getElementById("trafficcams").innerHTML = "<p id="display2"><big><b>Choose a map</b></big></p>"
                break;
            case "1":
                document.getElementById("trafficcams").innerHTML = "<img src="map_img1"/>"
                break;
            case "2":
                document.getElementById("trafficcams").innerHTML = "<img src="map_img2"/>"
                break;
            case "3":
                document.getElementById("trafficcams").innerHTML = "<img src="map_img3"/>"
                break;
            case "4":
                document.getElementById("trafficcams").innerHTML = "<img src="map_img4"/>"
                break;
            }
    }
</script>

<div id="trafficcams" align="middle" width="400" height="400">
</div>

<div id="menulist" align="middle">
    <select onchange="selectTrafficCamera(this.value);">
        <option value="0" selected="selected">Select Traffic Cam</option>
        <option value="1">Brisbane City</option>
        <option value="2">Rochedale</option>
        <option value="3">Logan City</option>
        <option value="4">Nerang</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Basically I'm trying to say when a different option is selected in the menu drop down, change the image in the div tag, unfortunately this isn't working for me and I'm unsure why it isn't. I also tried creating an img tag with a blank src inside the div and rather than using innerHTML I would use .src which also didn't work. Would I be able to get some insight on this please?

Thanks in advance.

**just for clarification, the map_img1, etc. is actually a url in the format url(imagename).jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your quotes are messed up for the new `<p>` and `<img>` tags.

Change these:

```
= "<p id="display2"><big><b>Choose a map</b></big></p>"
// and
= "<img src="map_img3"/>"
// and the rest
```

to these:

```
= "<p id='display2'><big><b>Choose a map</b></big></p>"
// and
= "<img src='map_img3' />"
// and the rest
```

Otherwise, everything looks fine.

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/bEvLS/

Also make sure the images have the correct source - normally, image files have an extension (`.png`, `.gif`, `.jpg`, etc.). And make sure they are in the same directory as this HTML file, because that's what you're saying by not giving a path, and just using a filename.

Another option is having the HTML actually there, then just hiding/showing and changing the `src`. Like this:

```
<div id="trafficcams" align="middle" width="400" height="400">
    <p id="display2"><big><b>Choose a map</b></big></p>
    <img id="displayImg" src="" style="display:none;" />
</div>
```

And use this JS:

```
function selectTrafficCamera(inobj) {
    if (inobj === "0") {
        document.getElementById("display2").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("displayImg").style.display = "none";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("display2").style.display = "none";
        var img = document.getElementById("displayImg");
        img.src = "map_img" + inobj;
        img.style.display = "inline";
    }
}
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/gbdV2/2/

Comment: Just tried changing the quotes but it didn't work :/

All the urls end with .jpg as well.

Comment: @user2279496 Did you mean to leave out the file extension? And are the images in the same directory as your HTML file?

Comment: Just for clarification, since I didn't put the urls in the question, it's like this: url\(imagename).jpg

Comment: Well I swapped the code around to having the html there and changing it as you did, and it worked! Still unsure why the switch statement isn't working for me though, but thanks a tonne (:

Comment: @user2279496 Hmm I'm really not sure. Can you check your browser's console and see if any errors are thrown? I'm glad the other option worked at least. It's how I would've done it in the first place - it's a lot easier hiding/showing the setting the `innerHTML`

Comment: Oh I didn't change the "<p id="display2">" part to "<p id="'display2'>" which was then automatically stopping the function, haha. Thanks a lot for the response (:

Answer (score 0):

A couple things, as mentioned above, you need to escape the strings in the img tags and in the chose a map message.

Also, you don't really need a switch statement, you can simplify your code with the following...

```
<div id="trafficcams" align="middle" style="width:400px;height:100px"><p id="display2"><big><b>Choose a map</b></big></p></div>
<div id="menulist" align="middle">
    <select id="trafficCamSelect">
        <option value="0" selected="selected">Select Traffic Cam</option>
        <option value="map_img1">Brisbane City</option>
        <option value="map_img2">Rochedale</option>
        <option value="map_img3">Logan City</option>
        <option value="map_img4">Nerang</option>
    </select>
</div>
<script>
document.getElementById('trafficCamSelect').addEventListener('change', function (evt) {
    var imgName = this.value,
        el = document.getElementById("trafficcams");

    if (imgName === "0") {

        el.innerHTML = '<p id="display2"><big><b>Choose a map</b></big></p>';
    } else {

        el.innerHTML = '<img src="' + imgName + '" />';
    }
});
</script>
```

By moving the image names into the values of your options, you make your JS simpler and easier to read/maintain.